# How can I take the ids of the registrations with the highest temperature of each day (on a specified period of time)?

Tags: php, mysql

Considering I have more than 30 registers/day for that temperature.

- Name of the table: 'temperatures'
- Colomn name: 'TempA'

I want one registration for each day, for example:

```
date: 2015-12-10 12:02 id: 2341 tempa: 54 (which is the highest on that day)
date: 2015-12-09 15:04 id 1923 tempa: 32 (which is the highest on that day)
```

and so on....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use max and group by

```
select max(TempA) from your_table group by day_column
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select id from temperatures where TempA=(select max(TempA) from temperatures )
```

Comment: It's ok, but not for what I want to receive from the database.